# Run process blocking signals from terminal

Tags: ruby, process, signals

If I run ruby script from terminal and run some other process using `system` from it and press Ctrl+C, than INT is sent to the other process, how can I make ruby process to handle it and the other process not to get it at all?

Example:

```
trap('INT'){ puts 'Wait a bit' }
system 'sleep 100'
```

If I press Ctrl+C this script will exit immediately and will not print anything: INT will be sent only to sleep, so it will exit and script will be finished.

Answer (score 0):

You might be talking about forking, rather than using system. The section on [`Independent Children`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/tut_threads.html#UH) in Programming Ruby might help.

Or, you might be talking about running the child completely detached from the parent as a standalone app, so that if the parent quits the child continues, like httpd servers and the like. I haven't tried it but [`Daemons`](http://daemons.rubyforge.org/) sounds like it'd work nicely.

Answer (score 0):

You can trap `INT` and and exit, using `trap("INT") { exit }`. Like Greg, not sure if this is what you wanted, but it might be something to look in to.